# Have a docker container use a proxy inside another docker container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, proxy

Let's say I have two docker containers. One containing an image with a proxy on `0.0.0.0:PORT`. The other container needs to use that proxy.

To clarify, I DO NOT want to use the host for anything here. So no `network_mode: host` and running the proxy on the host machine. I want to containerize both the proxy and the service that will use that proxy.

I use docker-compose so if you could provide me with an example of that, I would be glad.

If you need to know, the proxy is the tor proxy using [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/osminogin/tor-simple/).

Thank you! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `bridge` networking mode, which is the default for docker compose. Just to give you an example:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  tor:
    image: osminogin/tor-simple
    restart: always

  curl:
    image: curlimages/curl
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: ["sh"]
    depends_on:
      - tor
```

Here you can see that we set up a the `tor-simple` proxy and a `curlimages` which obviously will be used to send a request to the Tor network via the proxy. By default docker compose will set up a single network in which each container's host name will be the container name itself, so `tor` for the proxy and `curl` for the `curlimage`.

To prove that we can connect to tor with the proxy, first we bring up the containers with `docker compose up`. Then we can attach to the curl image with `docker attach <image-id>`, which will give us a shell (`command: [sh]` and also `curl` is running in interactive mode)

Now, we should validated our Tor connection:

```
curl --socks5 tor:9050 --socks5-hostname tor:9050 -s https://check.torproject.org/ | cat | grep -m 1 Congratulations | xargs
```

Pleas note that `curl` will connect to `tor-simple` using port `9500` (`tor:9050`) which will proxy the request to `https://check.torproject.org/`.

This should print something like:

```
Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
```